# Андроид SQL . Обработать клик в ListView с получением данных из SQL

Tags: java, android, sql

Всем привет!
Задача такова , получить данные из готовой SQL базы и вывести в ListView и затем при клике на каком либо из пунктов списка получить данные из второй таблицы по id.
Данные из таблицы я получил но как теперь обработать клик ?

**Вот так я получаю данные:**

```
 //Список клиентов
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> clients = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

 //Список параметров конкретного клиента
     HashMap<String, Object> client;

 //Отправляем запрос в БД
     Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM clients", null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();

 //Пробегаем по всем клиентам
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            client = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            //Заполняем клиента
            client.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            client.put("age", cursor.getString(2));

            //Закидываем клиента в список клиентов
            clients.add(client);

            //Переходим к следующему клиенту
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();

//Какие параметры клиента мы будем отображать в соответствующих
//элементах из разметки adapter_item.xml
        String[] from = {"name", "age"};
        int[] to = {R.id.textView, R.id.textView2};

//Создаем адаптер
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, clients, R.layout.adapter_item, from, to);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно создать слушателя на клик по элементу в ListView:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
          int position, long id) {

        // Получаем кликнутый элемент списка из адаптера
        Log.v("Client item:", adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString());
         
    }
});
```

Или через лямбду:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
          int position, long id) -> {
        Log.v("Client item:", adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString());
    }
});
```